# Using the master theorem to find an expression for T(n) in Big Oh

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

Solve the recurrence relation $T(n)$ = $2T$($\frac n 3$) + $c\sqrt2^{logn}$
, T(1) = 1, by finding an expression for T(n) in big-Oh notation.

So I'd like to solve this using the master theorem but I was confused on how to use it here.

> Master Theorem -
>
> $f(n) = af(\frac n b) + Cn^d$
>
> O $(n^d)$  When a < $b^d$
>
> O $(n^{d}log(n))$  When a = $b^d$
>
> O $(n^{log_ba})$  When a > $b^d$

going off of this

we get

a = 2

and $b^d$ = $3^{logn}$

now as far as the relation goes as long as n>= 5

a < $b^d$

but I'm not sure if that's how it's supposed to be used,since I am a beginner. How do i deal with the fact that it's $logn$ and how can T(1) = 1 be used in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{2}^{\log n}
=e^{\frac12\log 2 \log n}
=(e^{\log n})^{\frac12\log 2}
=n^{\frac12\log 2}
$
so
$d = \frac12\log 2
=\log\sqrt{2}
$.

Since $a=2, b=3$,
$b^d
=3^{\log\sqrt{2}}
=e^{\log 3\log\sqrt{2}}
\sim 1.46338
$
so that
$a > b^d$
(I originally had "<" here - oops)
and the third case,
$f(n) = O(n^{log_ba})
=O(n^{\log_32}$
holds.

$\log_32 \approx 0.5991
$.